Why is pqxdh of Signal not secure against active adversaries while PQ3 of iMessage is?
I was going through the official documentation of pqxdh  and A Formal Analysis of the iMessage PQ3 Messaging Protocol for PQ3.
The distinct difference I noticed is that pqxdh is not secure against active adversaries while PQ3 is. Is there a clear explanation or documentation about why PQ3 provides post-compromise security against active adversaries?

I think that this is more a question of modelling assumptions. If we look at the pqxdh specification section 4.8, we see a description of an active quantum attacker's possible approach:

PQXDH is not designed to provide protection against active quantum attackers. An active attacker with access to a quantum computer capable of computing discrete logarithms in curve can compute DH(PK1, PK2) and Sig(PK, M, Z) for all elliptic curve keys PK1, PK2, and PK. This allows an attacker to impersonate Alice by using the quantum computer to compute the secret key corresponding to PKA then continuing with the protocol. A malicious server with access to such a quantum computer could impersonate Bob by generating new key pairs PQSPK’B and PQOPK’B, computing the secret key corresponding to PKB, then using PKB to sign the newly generated post-quantum KEM keys and delivering these attacker-generated keys in place of Bob’s post-quantum KEM key when Alice requests a prekey bundle.

Conversely in the PQ3 analysis section 2.2 we can read

We assume that the adversary does not yet possess a quantum computer.
The adversary anticipates developments in quantum computing and thus
stores all messages sent. Therefore, they may be able break cryptographic
primitives later, should sufficiently powerful quantum computers become
available (also called “harvest now, decrypt later”). The only limitation we
place on this adversary is that they cannot decapsulate secrets that were
encapsulated with a post-quantum secure KEM like Kyber. But all other
mechanisms, like (elliptic-curve) Diffie-Hellman, can be broken at that point.

The adversary described in the pqxdh explicitly does have a quantum computer at the time of the communication and so the two security models are distinct.

Could you explain what makes the adversary as defined for PQ3 "active"? To me, "harvest now, decrypt later" sounds very much passive. What active operations can that adversary perform while the communication is in progress when they don't have a quantum computer at that point?

@TooTea Again in section 2: " As an active network adversary, the adversary can
read, reorder, intercept, replay, and send any message to any participant." In particular they can send new key pair messages, but their ability to have these keys accepted is only as strong as their ability to forge Sig() outputs at the time of sending. The PQXDH model grants this ability; the PQ3 model does not.

I am unsure why the models are considered different. Both cases only prove security against a "post-quantum" adversary (in addition to proving other types of security). Can you expand more?
